# Followed a rigging tutorial from Ryan King Art on youtube, and one arm on my rigged character deforms, how can I fix this?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, surface-deform

[image: one arm works, one arm deforms]

I created a rig for this character using symmetrize, and the weight paints look identical from one arm to the other. But for whatever reason, one side functions, and the other side does not. The bones do not stay inside the geometry of one arm, and when moved it makes the arm squish and bend in strange ways. I tried removing the armature from the broken side and mirroring from the good side again, and did the same with the arm geometry itself, but the problem persisted. This is the only spot on the character that does not bend properly.

Comment: Also looks like those control points at the elbows are in different places making me think there is a twist somewhere.

Comment: I had actually moved the elbow ik myself before taking the photo, I was trying to see if moving it did anything. But I'll try to look at the rolls on the bones to see if they are maybe out of whack.